# Conditionally manipulate hash in StackExchange.Redis relying on some synchronization

Tags: c#, caching, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I'm using redis backed with some underlying persistent storage, so when cache request misses, logic is about to fetch data from backed storage and pass it to client storing it in cache as well.
When some simultaneous requests for missed key happens I do want to permit only one request to reach persistent storage and do the job, while other will lock or have been subscribed for key changes and return to caller with values fetched from cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach could be adding a string key with expiration ([see `EXPIRE` command](http://redis.io/commands/expire)) whenever the cache needs to be populated called `whatever:lock` (change *whatever* with something meaningful to your project) and expire it in 4-5 minutes.

All requests to the cache should check if `whatever:lock` is present:

- If it's not present, then the whole process adds the whole locking key and tries to populate the cache.
- If it's present, the whole process will poll the cache until the locking key doesn't exist anymore, and it will get the data from the cache.

Both `SET` and `EXPIRE` should be issued as part of a [`MULTI` command](http://redis.io/commands/multi) to be sure that expiration is set atomically along with the key creation.

You can use `SETNX` for this too. [Check Redis official doc about this command, where it says that it can be used to create locks](http://redis.io/commands/setnx).

Comment: Thank you, Matías. I have ended with almost the same approach, however I did subscribtion on 'hset' keyevent instead polling.